# Passing an array via HTML select with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, select

Is this possible:

I am using an Ajax call to grab some results of a SQL query. The results are returns in an array which I echo as JSON at the end of a PHP script (which the ajax calls).

Then for each row of the sql result I am using 'append' to add an option to an html select as follows:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "DoSQL.php",
     data: dataString,
     success:function(reply){

          $.each(reply, function(x, row){

               $('#mySel').append($('<option>', {value: row, text:'Some text'}));

          });

     });
```

As you can see I am giving the value of the select option an array. Then I am detecting when the select is changed, but the value is returned as an object. Can I pass the array as the value and if so how do I access its contents:

```
$("#mySel").change(function(){

 var result=$('#matchSel').val();

 alert(result);

})
```

Thanks in advance,

Alan.

**EDIT:** 'fixture' was an error, it should be 'row'. I have corrected my example code above. I'm trying to return the result of the mysql query to the html select.

**EDIT**: Here is the PHP code as requesteD:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `table1`";

$result=$mysqli->query($query);

while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     $res[]=$row;

}

$mysqli->close();

echo json_encode($res);
```

So the array `$res` is what is returned as `reply` and then assigned to `row`

Comment: So you want to store the entire array as an `option` value?

Comment: What is 'fixture'. Seems like that's an object.

Comment: You can store an array in option by making it a string separated by a ny separator.when you select that option again parse this string into array using js. like <option value="x,y,z">xyzf</option>

Comment: You have syntax errors in your append and we need to know where "fixture" declared and assigned a value

Comment: @tymeJV - yes an array as an option

Comment: @koala_dev - the syntax error should have been removed, 'fixture' was an error, should be 'row'. I've corrected the example now...

Comment: Ok, can you show us the PHP code where you send the JSON result

Comment: @koala_dev I've added the php in the 2nd edit as requested

Comment: Do you really need to have all your row data as the value in the option? typically you would just use the id of the row as the option value

Comment: @koala_dev the row data is used to autofill a form when the select is made. One option as to just was the id but then it would require a further query of the database. The database has already been queried in order to get the text for the select menu. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, you can also store your data in an array with the id as the index, then set the value of the option to the id so it would be easy to retrieve the data when the select value changes

Answer (score 1):

This way of attaching event will not work as it's a Dynamically added element

```
$("#mySel").change(function() {
```

**You need to delegate the event**

```
$(document).on("change", "#mySel", function(){
```

If **fixture** is an array instance here. You can use the `index` of the array which is `x` argument

```
 value: fixture[x],
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but your last code block makes it seem like you are asking how to get at the item selected? :

`var result=$('select.foo option:selected').val();`

If not please clarify.

Comment: yes that's what I am trying to do, my code enables me to select the data but I get an object, I'm not sure if I have to Jsno decode?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. MY php script was only echoing the JSON response back to the Jscript, in order to pass the array I had to encode it implicitly with JSON:

```
var temp=JSON.stringify(fixture);

$('#mySel').append($('<option>', {value: temp, text:'my text'}));
```

Then I decode the JSon when the select is made:

```
$("#mySel").change(function(){

     var obj=jQuery.parseJSON($('#mySel').val());    

})
```

Thanks for th hints and letting me think aloud!

Alan